# How do I cast this pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following struct:

```
    struct Map {
    void* arr; // includes pointers to certain blocks of memory
    int mem_block_count;
    };
```

The void* arr holds pointers to certain cells in memory. Each cell holds a void* pointer to another cell in memory (as a linked list) a char* string, and a value with its own size.

You should be able to grab one of these pointers to a cell by doing arr[i] where i is an index - is this right?

I am trying to access the first pointer to one of these cells, which is probably arr[0]. Then, I want to get access to the pointer to the next cell in memory. But this is of void type. So how do I get at it? For getting access to the char*, I just move forward in memory, and then do a strcpy. But how do I get access/deref the next pointer?

EDIT: I also thought about casting the void pointer to an int, but I'm not sure I would get the right value. Something like:

```
    int *next_pointer;
    next_pointer = (int*) map->arr[i]
```

But is this not preserving the pointer to the pointer when I cast this as an int? How do I dereference a pointer to a pointer correctly?

EDIT - Couldn't I also, because it is a linked list of pointers, also do something like - map->arr + index * sizeof(void*) to get to the start of a given cell?

Comment: Do `arr` always point to the same kind of structure, or can different `arr` point to different structures?

Comment: You need pointers to pointers: `void **arr;`

Comment: `void *arr;` is a single pointer, not "pointers".  If you mean that it points to a block of memory in which some pointers are stored, then you have to supply those details before dereferencing. The `void *` does not remember from whence it came.

Comment: @pmg Sorry where would the pointer to pointer go?

Comment: @MattMcNabb So the void *arr points to the first "cell" in memory, and since each cell has a pointer to the next cell in it, that's how it becomes something like an "array"

Comment: It would be more useful if you specified exactly how these "cells" had been created, e.g. show the code that sets them up.  It is not possible to "autodetect" what types of variable are stored in memory; your code has to specify the correct types and locations for what it is accessing.

Comment: If a "cell" has a pointer to the next "cell", that sounds more like a singly linked list than an array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that's right. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pointers to pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Map {
    void **arr; // includes pointers to certain blocks of memory
    int mem_block_count;
};

int main(void) {
    struct Map map = {0};
    int a1[100];
    double a2[100];
    char a3[100];

    map.arr = malloc(3 * sizeof *map.arr);
    if (!map.arr) /* error */;

    a1[42] = 42;
    a2[42] = 42;
    a3[42] = 42;
    map.mem_block_count = 3;
    map.arr[0] = a1;
    map.arr[1] = a2;
    map.arr[2] = a3;

    printf("%d %f %c\n", ((int *)(map.arr[0]))[42],
                         ((double *)(map.arr[1]))[42],
                         ((char *)(map.arr[2]))[42]);

    free(map.arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is excellent. How would I dereference the pointer, though, to get access to the void* pointer, the char* and the value in contiguous memory that an individual pointer in the pointers points to?

Comment: It makes no sense to access the contents of a `void*`. *The contents of a `void*` are of type `void`. You cannot do anything with values of type `void`.*

Comment: Right - but how would I get access to the other two then? I was under the impression that you kind of needed to know something about void* (possibly only the size) to get to the next two elements in the memory? So how would I get to the char*?

Comment: This is why you need pointers to pointers. You can use the contents of a `void**`: they're simply pointers.

Comment: So you would dereference one pointer from the void**, say the first one, like so - map->arr[0]. This gives us the first pointer. Then you can do something like pointer arithmetic, map->arr[0] + sizeof(void*) to get to the char* src? And then strcpy from there?

Comment: `map->arr[0] + sizeof (void*)` is the same as `map->arr[1]`. After you cast the 2nd level pointers to the correct type, you can do whatever you like.

Comment: Sorry - one last clarification. Once I do get to the first pointer to a pointer, void **pointer = map->arr[1]. with **pointer, you still have a pointer to a pointer, but can you use it as the pointer itself? So whatever arithmetic you do on pointer is basically like getting to the second level of pointers, as long as you cast the types correctly?

Comment: No, no. `map->arr[1]` is not a pointer to pointer. With the `[1]` you dereference it and obtain a regular pointer. `void *pointer = map->arr[1];` **Also note the first pointer is at index `0`!**

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's right. Apologies - just starting out. What I understand now is that you have some void **arr, pointers to pointers, and doing map->arr[1] gives you the first cell of memory...

Comment: `arr[1]` gives you **the second element**. Arrays, in C, start at index `0`. **This is important!**

Comment: That's what I meant! Anyway, is this understanding correct? That the dereferenced pointer is a regular pointer to a certain cell in memory as per the question above?

Comment: Yes, that is right. A dereferenced `void **` is a regular pointer that you must convert to the proper type (with a cast) before using.

Comment: Very last question - once you get the regular pointer, how do you get void pointer within the block of memory which points to the next cell since it is a linked list?

Comment: The conversion from any "pointer to an object" to a "void pointer" is automatic. Just assign it. If you mean a `void **` you need to cast.

Comment: So from the regular pointer void *pointer, to get to the next cell in memory, I would just do void **next_cell = pointer? How would this account for the size of the pointer, and the fact that I don't want to copy other things in contiguous memory? Sorry - your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot dereference void pointers. You cannot do pointer arithmetic on void pointers. Size of pointers is irrelevant to your most recent question. Assigning a void pointer to a variable of type `void **` is well defined. I think maybe you should ask another question rather than extend this discussion even more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use array indexing on a `void` pointer, as it really just a generic pointer without a type. And if there's no type then there's no way of adding the correct offset to the base memory address. You have to cast it to the correct structure before using array indexing:

```
((struct some_structure *) arr)[1]
```

Comment: Couldn't I also, because it is a linked list of pointers, also do something like - map->arr + index * sizeof(void*) to get to the start of a given cell?